# How to turn MongoDB collection into a 'Table'

Tags: mongodb-query

I've been given access to a cloud MongoDB (MongoLab) and need to extract some data into Excel so I can analyse it. The data isn't particularly complicated or large and is well suited to a 'normal' relational structure.

My research suggests things are trickier because the data has 'nested' aspects although conceptually its pretty clear how this would become a table. Here is what a document in the collection looks like, essntinaly the stuff highlighted blue would be columns in the table while the yellow would create a row for each "marketing_event" with the specifics of each event also being in a column:

[image]

Ideally I would use Power Query to get the data into Power Pivot but at this point anything will do!

I've tried a bunch of things all of which haven't got me much closer to end result that I'm looking for:

- I downloaded MongoVue which I used to successfully connect to the database and while it enabled me to see the data in a basic table form, it does nothing with the nested stuff and the documentation is minimal in terms of how it could be of more use.
- I also tried Pentaho PDI based on this article:http://sqlmag.com/blog/integrating-mongodb-and-open-source-data-stores-power-pivot but the steps aren't detailed and although I can see the collection, trying to replicate some sample queries I found on the web were totally unsuccesful.
- I've tried to get a trial of Simba's ODBC connector but as yet the download doesn't seem to be working. I have contacted them but without response just yet.
- I've even installed Mongo locally and tried to use the command prompt to connect which I was unable to do. Even if I pursued this I wouldn't be confident about knowing where to start in terms of creating the end product.

Happy to hear any suggestions or recommendations.

TIA
Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solid ODBC driver that helps maintain the fidelity of your mongoDB data by exposing the nested MongoDB data model as a set of relational tables to Excel and other ODBC apps.  in the sample document above, this driver will do *exactly* what you're looking for.  The embedded documents and arrays can be extracted as separate related tables from the fields at the root level of the document.

https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already found the solution - but Simba ODBC is providing support for nested arrays.

Have a look here: 
https://www.simba.com/resources/webinars/connect-tableau-big-data-source. This is an example how to connect Tableau BI to MongoDB. You might find it helpful.

And some more information on handling no-sql data in BI tools is provided in this whitepaper: http://info.mongodb.com/rs/mongodb/images/MongoDB_BI_Analytics.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response. Simba does support nested arrays, the issue is that it doesn't give you a choice about how it handles them and simply adds columns to your dataset where in my case it would be prefereable for them to be additional rows.